# MS Excel Value Range Equivalent (IF Statement)

Tags: excel

What is wrong with my `formula`?

```
=if(((F2 >= 97) and (f2 <= 100)), "Excellent", if(((f2 >= 94) and (f2 <= 96)), "Good", "None of the Above"))
```

i am creating a worksheet that displays it equivalent grade. Here is the range:

```
97 - 100  ==>  Excellent
94 -  96  ==>  Good
and so on and so forth...
```

or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> or is there a better way to do this?

You can use LOOKUP to shorten the formula. You need to specifiy the lower bound of each range, e.g.

`=IF(F2="","",LOOKUP(F2,{0,70,80,90,94,97},{"Poor","Average","Above Average","Below Good","Good","Excellent"}))`

.....best way IMO would be to put all the values in a table, so using my example you could list 0, 70, 80 etc. in Y2:Y7 and the associated text in Z2:Z7 and then formula is simply

`=IF(F2="","",LOOKUP(F2,$Y$2:$Z$7))`

That's much easier to maintain and you can easily change the breakpoints or text etc. by changing the table, without touching the formulas

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(AND(F2>=97,F2<=100),"Excellent",IF(AND(F2>=94,F2<=96),"Good","None of the Above"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that this is a slightly better way than barry houdini's (very clever!) answer:

`=IF(F2="","",INDEX({"Poor","Average","Above Average","Below Good","Good","Excellent"},MATCH(F2,{0,70,80,90,94,97})))`

From what I understand, `LOOKUP` is a volatile function(EDIT: turns out it isn't!), which means if you have a lot of `LOOKUP` functions in your spreadsheet it can begin to get slow.

Comment: No, `LOOKUP` isn't volatile, see this link: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm - `LOOKUP` works in a very similar way to the `MATCH` function here, using "binary search", which is very fast - but with a 6 row table you won't really notice. When I tested the speed a LOOKUP formula referencing 10,000 rows took a millionth of a second!

Answer (score 0):

> =IF(F7="","",INDEX({"D","C","B","A"},MATCH(F7,{0,26,51,76,101})))

If result value in F7 cell than it may be used for Range grade A (76-100 Marks), B(51-75 marks), C (26-50 marks),  D (0-25 marks)

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple as this `=IF(A:A>75,"PASS",IF(A:A<75,"FAILED"))` and so on.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to format your code by enclosing it in backticks or indenting it four spaces.